Find 2nd level leader that fits criteria from hierarchy columns
I have to create a column that identifies a person's 2nd-level manager based on hierarchy.
I have columns named ManLev01Band through ManLev11Band that contain a number followed by some letters. Example: 5trxn. The first character is all that matters here.
What I need to do is figure out the first leader in each employee's hierarchy that contains a band less than 6. The catch here is it needs to be at least two levels above that person's own position in the hierarchy.
Here is an example of the data with the Result column being the one that I want to generate:



EmployeeName
AssignedManagementLevel
ManLev02Band
ManLev03Band
ManLev04Band
ManLev05Band
ManLev06Band
ManLev07Band
ManLev08Band
ManLev09Band
ManLev10Band
ManLev11Band
Result




John
8
2yiol
3koli
4jkli
5zvd
6wehe
7werf




5zvd


Jake
6
2yiol
3koli
4jkli
5zvd






4jkli


Jen
5
2yiol
3koli
4jkli







3koli



Note that for all scenarios, the first non-blank value is the first level leader. We are looking for the second level position or greater depending on the band level #.
For John, the result is band 5zvd. It is the third band available so it meets the criteria of at least 2nd level leader. 6wehe does not qualify because it is not <= band 5.
For Jake, while band 5zvd qualifies on the first criteria of being <= band 5, it is not a second-level leader. They are a 1st level. So we go onto the next.
With Jen the second level leader is a band 3 that meets the criteria of <= band 5. So the result for her is 3koli.

Your data looks denormalised to me; storing up to 10 managers in a user's row isn't th "best™" of ideas. Why not just have an employee/manager relationship and then you can traverse through said hierarchy? The data to be given us doesn't look like a hierarchy to me.

I'm not sure what you mean. I have other columns that list the manager's name. For example ManLev04Name but I didn't think that would be relevant. The position of band levels for these managers is relevant because we are specifically looking for a band <=5 that is in that second position. Hope that clears things up.

So why do you have 10 ManLevBand columns, and not n rows (where n is the appropriate number of rows for the employee)? Why do you need 7 empty columns for Jen, when they could just have 3 rows.

There are over 200K employees in this database. So that's 200K rows already. While Jen doesn't utilize all columns there are plenty of others who do. This is just how the database has been set up. I have to work with what I have, unfortunately.

@DanCue - a common way to store this data is to have only one column that stores the employee's immediate manager or a materialized path of all of their managers. That should assuage your concern of the number of rows being e*n.

@BenThul understood. We do have a column with immediate manager and we have another column with assigned management level which provides the position they are in the hierarchy... or the first null value in the hierarchy. (John is level 8, Jake is 6 and Jen is 5) Would either of those columns help? I know the latter would for samahita's answer. Let me add that detail in my question.

@BogdanSahlean What is this?

@DanCue Nonsense, NLN flag it

You can directly calculate for your scenario
select EmpId,EmployeeName
  ,case when ManLev11Band is not null and left(ManLev10Band,1)<=5 then ManLev10Band
        when ManLev10Band is not null and left(ManLev09Band,1)<=5 then ManLev09Band
        when ManLev09Band is not null and left(ManLev08Band,1)<=5 then ManLev08Band
        when ManLev08Band is not null and left(ManLev07Band,1)<=5 then ManLev07Band
        when ManLev07Band is not null and left(ManLev06Band,1)<=5 then ManLev06Band
        when ManLev06Band is not null and left(ManLev05Band,1)<=5 then ManLev05Band
        when ManLev05Band is not null and left(ManLev04Band,1)<=5 then ManLev04Band
        when ManLev04Band is not null and left(ManLev03Band,1)<=5 then ManLev03Band
        when ManLev03Band is not null and left(ManLev02Band,1)<=5 then ManLev02Band
   end Result
  ,testResult
  ,ManLev02Band,ManLev03Band,ManLev04Band,ManLev05Band,ManLev06Band,ManLev07Band
  ,ManLev08Band,ManLev09Band,ManLev10Band,ManLev11Band
from test




EmpId
EmployeeName
Result
testResult
ManLev02Band
ManLev03Band
ManLev04Band
ManLev05Band
ManLev06Band
ManLev07Band
ManLev08Band
ManLev09Band
ManLev10Band
ManLev11Band




1
John
5zvd
5zvd
2yiol
3koli
4jkli
5zvd
6wehe
7werf
null
null
null
null


2
Jake
4jkli
4jkli
2yiol
3koli
4jkli
5zvd
null
null
null
null
null
null


3
Jen
3koli
3koli
2yiol
3koli
4jkli
null
null
null
null
null
null
null



There should also be acceptable performance here.
fiddle
Update1. For question from @samhita.
Column testResut in example - only for debug,test and clarity. That is what we should get by query.
See fiddle

I added these 2 rows
,(4,'employeeX',9,'2yiol','3koli','4jkli','6zvd', '6wehe' , '7werf', '9tyui' , null, null,null,null)
,(5,'employeeY',10,'2yiol','3koli','3jkli', '4zvd' , '4wehe' , '5werf', '5tyui' ,'9tyui', '8yuty','7abcd',null)
result appears to be null, not sure if I am missing something

If you about testResult->null: Last column in example is check value for test - what we waiting as result. Put it manually. For example test data should be (4,'employeeX',9,'2yiol','3koli','4jkli','6zvd', '6wehe' , '7werf', '9tyui' , null, null,null,'4jkli')

I really like this solution. It fits quite well with the SQL I currently have. Performance-wise it is acceptable, as you mentioned. One question for you though. I have corresponding columns to go along with ManLevXXBand like ManLevXXEmail and ManLevXXFirstName. I want to populate a column for Email and first name as well. I know that I can just repeat this code and replace those after the then statement, but is there a way to do these other columns in one go? If not, it's not a big deal.

You can once calculate shift level and then use choose(...) several times. See example(https://dbfiddle.uk/Ay0YUvMw)

Just another option sans CTE
Not sure on the performance for a 200K, but should be easy enough to test.
To be clear, you could declare @variables for the two thresholds.... ie. 6 & 2
Example or dbFiddle
Select A.EmployeeName 
      ,A.AssignedManagementLevel
      ,ColName  = B.[key]
      ,ColValue = B.[Value]
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( Select *
                     ,Seq = row_number() over (order by [key] desc) 
                From  OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )) 
                Where [Key] Not in ('EmployeeName','AssignedManagementLevel','Other','Colums2Exclude')
                  and [Value]<>''
                  and try_convert(int,replace(replace([key],'ManLev',''),'Band','')) <=6
             ) B
 Where Seq = 2

Results
EmployeeName    AssignedManagementLevel ColName         ColValue
John            8                       ManLev05Band    5zvd
Jake            6                       ManLev04Band    4jkli
Jen             5                       ManLev03Band    3koli


From the question I have assumed there is static band of managers, so here are the steps.
My previous answer was calculating the second level manager by first calculating first not null managers and then traversing through till second level.
EDIT : As per new column AssignedManagementLevel and additional check whether or not the first character is less than or 5.

CTE secondlevelmanagers finds the second level band  based on AssignedManagementLevel and the condition that second level should be less than or equal to 5.

Once the target level is known , we then self-join to the base table to fetch the second level manager alogside a check whether or not the first character is less than or equal to 5.If not then traverse back to find the band where the first character is equal to or less than 5


Fiddle
with secondlevelmanagers as (
    select 
        employeename,
        assignedmanagementlevel,
        
   assignedmanagementlevel - 2 as targetlevel
    from employeehierarchy
),

secondlevelmanagers_with_check as (
    select 
        sm.employeename,
        sm.targetlevel,
        case 
            when sm.targetlevel = 9 and left(e.manlev09band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev09band
            when sm.targetlevel = 8 and left(e.manlev08band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev08band
            when sm.targetlevel = 7 and left(e.manlev07band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev07band
            when sm.targetlevel = 6 and left(e.manlev06band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev06band

            when sm.targetlevel = 5 and left(e.manlev05band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev05band
            when sm.targetlevel = 4 and left(e.manlev04band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev04band
            when sm.targetlevel = 3 and left(e.manlev03band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev03band
            when sm.targetlevel = 2 and left(e.manlev02band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev02band
            when sm.targetlevel = 9 and left(e.manlev09band, 1) > '5' then 
            case 
                    when left(e.manlev08band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev08band
                    when left(e.manlev07band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev07band
                    when left(e.manlev06band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev06band
                    when left(e.manlev05band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev05band
                    when left(e.manlev04band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev04band
                    when left(e.manlev03band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev03band
                    when left(e.manlev02band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev02band
                    else null
                end 
            when sm.targetlevel = 8 and left(e.manlev08band, 1) > '5' then 
            case 
                    when left(e.manlev07band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev07band
                    when left(e.manlev06band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev06band
                    when left(e.manlev05band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev05band
                    when left(e.manlev04band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev04band
                    when left(e.manlev03band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev03band
                    when left(e.manlev02band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev02band
                    else null
                end 
            when sm.targetlevel = 7 and left(e.manlev07band, 1) > '5' then 
            case 
                    when left(e.manlev06band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev06band
                    when left(e.manlev05band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev05band
                    when left(e.manlev04band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev04band
                    when left(e.manlev03band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev03band
                    when left(e.manlev02band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev02band
                    else null
                end 
  
  
            when sm.targetlevel = 6 and left(e.manlev06band, 1) > '5' then 
            case 
                    when left(e.manlev05band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev05band
                    when left(e.manlev04band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev04band
                    when left(e.manlev03band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev03band
                    when left(e.manlev02band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev02band
                    else null
                end          
  
  
                when sm.targetlevel = 5 and left(e.manlev05band, 1) > '5' then 
                case 
                    when left(e.manlev04band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev04band
                    when left(e.manlev03band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev03band
                    when left(e.manlev02band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev02band
                    else null
                end
            when sm.targetlevel = 4 and left(e.manlev04band, 1) > '5' then 
                case 
                    when left(e.manlev03band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev03band
                    when left(e.manlev02band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev02band
                    else null
                end
            when sm.targetlevel = 3 and left(e.manlev03band, 1) > '5' then 
                case 
                    when left(e.manlev02band, 1) <= '5' then e.manlev02band
                    else null
                end
            else null
        end as secondlevelmanager
    from secondlevelmanagers sm
    join employeehierarchy e
        on e.employeename = sm.employeename
)

select 
    employeename,
    secondlevelmanager
from secondlevelmanagers_with_check
order by employeename;

Output


What do you mean by static band of managers?

I meant it has 11 band of managers

Yes, that is correct. Here's a question. Would it help if I already had a column named AssignedManagementLevel, that tells you what level the employee is on in the hierarchy? For Example.. John is level 8, Jake is 6 and Jen is 5.

Yes that will help to reduce some of the  CASE statements

I updated the table in my question to add that column. I think that's what you are trying to get to with managerhierarchy minus 1.

What if it is not a static band of managers. I think I misunderstood what you meant by that. Are you saying that a person with a band 4xxx would always be in ManLev04Band? That will not always be the case.  4jkli could be anywhere in the ManLevXXBand columns. We need to do a check to see if the first character in the band is band 5 or less.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Take a look at the example. To begin with, let's put the data in a normalized form.
CTE data does this thru cross apply  - unpivot table.
row_number() ordered desc here only for next step.
Than we take rows with rn>=2. We are looking for the second level position or greater 
Than we take first row with ln<=5 that contains a band less than 6
with data as(
select empId,EmployeeName,l.*
  ,left(mnLvl,1) ln
  ,row_number()over(partition by EmpId order by ord desc)rn
from test
cross apply( values (2,ManLev02Band),(3,ManLev03Band),(4,ManLev04Band),
                    (5,ManLev05Band),(6,ManLev06Band),(7,ManLev07Band),
                    (8,ManLev08Band),(9,ManLev09Band),(10,ManLev10Band),
                    (11,ManLev11Band)
  )l(ord,mnLvl)
where mnLvl is not null
)
select *
from(  -- select second and and below not null values
       -- and first symbol<=5
select * 
  ,row_number()over(partition by EmpId order by rn) rn2
from data
where rn>=2 and ln<=5
)a
where rn2=1
order by empid,rn desc





empId
EmployeeName
ord
mnLvl
ln
rn
rn2




1
John
5
5zvd
5
3
1


2
Jake
4
4jkli
4
2
1


3
Jen
3
3koli
3
2
1



There CTE data output is



empId
EmployeeName
ord
mnLvl
ln
rn




1
John
2
2yiol
2
6


1
John
3
3koli
3
5


1
John
4
4jkli
4
4


1
John
5
5zvd
5
3


1
John
6
6wehe
6
2


1
John
7
7werf
7
1


2
Jake
2
2yiol
2
4


2
Jake
3
3koli
3
3


2
Jake
4
4jkli
4
2


2
Jake
5
5zvd
5
1


3
Jen
2
2yiol
2
3


3
Jen
3
3koli
3
2


3
Jen
4
4jkli
4
1



fiddle
